# Get a list of running WPF Windows on a WinForm application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, elementhost

I've implemented some new WPF stuff in a old WinForm app project and I used to run it as the following:

```
    WpfWindow win = new WpfWindow(); // is a subclass of System.Windows.Window
    System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(win);
    WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(win);
    helper.Owner = this.Handle;

    win.Show();
```

now the question is, how can I get a list of opened Windows? In a native WPF project I simply do:

```
var windows = Application.Current.Windows
```

but I did not find any way in a form project.

Comment: To get a list of open forms for a windows project [Application.OpenForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: Hi Karen and thanks for your comment, but as I stated in the title I'm running a WPF Window, i.e. System.Windows.Window. Not sure your suggestion will work....or I'm wrong?

Comment: Hi, I was keying off `but I did not find any way in a form project.`

Comment: See [How to: Get all Windows in an Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/how-to-get-all-windows-in-an-application?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for WPF

Comment: You can do the same thing that the current AppDomain does with the `Application.OpenForms` collection: build a `List<System.Windows.Window>`, say `openWindows`. When you create a new Window, add it to the collection, subscribe to the `Closed` event (using a method, not a Lambda). When you close the Window, the event is raised, cast `sender` to `System.Windows.Window`, remove the event handler and remove the Window from the collection (i.e., `var w = sender as System.Windows.Window; w.Closed -= [Closed Handler]; openWindows.Remove(w);`).

Comment: Hi @Jimi, I had already thought about a List of Window objects but was hoping for a native solution, and +1 for the event handler tip. For the second solution, if i'm not mistaken, I have to add the Window to a collection anyway, so the first solution appear to be more easy. Let you know

Comment: @Karen, thanks again but the link you posted points to a solution (which is already mentioned above in my question) that can work only if you run a native WPF app while this is not the case because it's a WinForm project with some WPF funtionalities say "transplanted", where Application.Current is simply null so cannot help here.

Comment: Well, you could extend the *concept*, build a small class Factory that initializes your Windows, subscribes to the event and handles the `List<Window>`. It could expose a generic method, e.g., `public T OpenWindow<T>(Form owner) where T : System.Windows.Window, new() { // Create a new Window of Type T, subscribe to the Closed event, add the Window to a collection and return the instance }`, so you just need to call the public method of the Factory, the rest is automatic. The Factory of course exposes methods that allow to query or modify the Collection.

Comment: Guys, I've accepted the answer from @Reza Aghaei. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you show the first Window, for example in startup of your application, create an instance of [System.Windows.Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) (and forget it).

```
var app = new System.Windows.Application();
```

Later, in your WinForms application, you can easily find all WPF windows:

```
var windows = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows
```

**Note:**

- Do this only once, for example in startup of the application. Look at [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Application.cs,124) of the application class.
- It's pretty similar to the way that a WPF app does it:

  ```
  public partial class App : System.Windows.Application 
  {
      ...
      ...
      ...         
      public static void Main() 
      {
          WpfApp1.App app = new WpfApp1.App();
          app.InitializeComponent();
          app.Run();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: It works like a sharm, thanks! (Well, the solution was under my nose  he he..)